# How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings while joining multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-group-concat

I'm joining multiple tables in which I want one column value into row according to `TechnicianName`:

- I have 4 tables `easy_tbljobcard` , `easy_tbltechnician` and `easy_tblproblem` and `easy_tbltechnicianMaster`
- I am getting `TechnicianName` in 2nd column from `easy_tbltechnicianMaster`  where `technicianId` exist in `easy_tbltechnician`
- I want `STUFF` in 3rd column in my query (`p.ProblemReported`)

*Current SQL statement:*

```
 SELECT j.CardID, 
      , (SELECT TechnicianName FROM easy_tbltechnicianMaster WHERE TechnicianID = t.technicianID) AS TechnicianName
      , p.ProblemReported 
 FROM easy_tbljobcard AS j 
 JOIN easy_technician AS t ON t.CardID = j.CardID  
 LEFT JOIN easy_tblproblem AS p ON p.CardID = t.CardID
```

*Query result:*

```
╔══════════╦══════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║  CardID  ║  TechnicianName  ║  ProblemReported  ║
╠══════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║    1     ║      AKBAR       ║     PROBLEM A     ║
║    1     ║      AKBAR       ║     PROBLEM B     ║
║    1     ║      AKBAR       ║     PROBLEM C     ║
║    1     ║      ASANKA      ║     PROBLEM A     ║
║    1     ║      ASANKA      ║     PROBLEM B     ║
║    1     ║      ASANKA      ║     PROBLEM C     ║
╚══════════╩══════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

*The result above should be converted into this :*

```
╔══════════╦══════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════╗
║  CardID  ║  TechnicianName  ║         ProblemReported         ║
╠══════════╬══════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║    1     ║      AKBAR       ║ PROBLEM A, PROBLEM B, PROBLEM C ║
║    1     ║      ASANKA      ║ PROBLEM A, PROBLEM B, PROBLEM C ║
╚══════════╩══════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════╝
```

How to do this while joining multiple tables ?

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b4f2/1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse i think it`s not duplicate.. can you plz provide me an example in which you can Group columns in one row with separator Specially while joining multiple tables as i said while joining multiple tables

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify a [CTE – common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms175972.aspx) to store your temporary result :

```
with cteTbl ( CardID
            , TechName
            , problemReported ) as ( 
select j.CardID
     , p.ProblemReported
     , ( select TechnicianName
         from easy_tbltechnicianMaster
         where TechnicianID =  t.technicianID ) as TechName
from easy_tbljobcard as j 
join easy_technician as t on t.CardID = j.CardID  
left join easy_tblproblem as p  on p.CardID = t.CardID )
```

And then `select` from it and concatenate all column values with the same `t.techName` and `t.CardID` in one row with `for xml path('')` and after that replace the first comma `,` with `stuff`:

```
select t.CardID
     , t.TechName
     , stuff( ( select ', ' + ProblemReported
                from cteTbl
                where TechName = t.TechName
                order by ProblemReported
                for xml path('') ), 1, 1, '') AS ProblemReported
from cteTbl t
group by t.TechName
       , t.CardID
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b4f2/7)

Comment: i need this while joining multiple tables, how to do that

Comment: @Siddiq Baig : Your question is too broad.Update your answer with your complex query, for example, specify, where do you need query with `STUFF` and so on.

Comment: @Siddiq Baig : It is hard for me now to understand what is wrong taking in consideration that the only feedback is "It is not working".Take my sql fiddle, update it with your three tables,insert necessary data and post here.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. i have updated my question with SQL Fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55602/discussion-between-siddiq-baig-and-notulysses).